# sharepoint Excel services poor Performanace

Tags: sharepoint-server, excel-services

I have a excel dashboard in SharePoint 2013 environment that takes for ever ( > 2 min) to open . is there any way anyone can help me in terms of performance tuning this service ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a few more details about the farm, including how many servers, servers specification (CPU, memory, network infrastructure) and which servers are running the Excel Services?